# React router 2.4.0 redirect incorrect behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Could someone provide me some help.

I'm new to reactjs and try implement simple app with the latest versions of react and react-router libs. I have found in docs API that Redirect element should work.

Main element

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var routes = require('./routes');
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Routes

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var IndexRoute = Router.IndexRoute;
var Route = Router.Route;
var PageNotFound = require('./components/NotFountpage');
var Redirect = Router.Redirect;

var routes  = (
    <Route path="/" component= {require('./components/app')} >
      <IndexRoute  component={ require('./components/homePage')} />
      <Route path="/about" component={require('./components/aboutPage')} />
      <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
      <Redirect from="/azaza" to="/about"/>
      </Route>
    )

module.exports = routes;
```

I don't know is that my error or something wrong with library version of this element. Also Page not found doesn't work in a proper way. Seems it's my fault by I can't fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Put the redirect before the `PageNotFound` route (assuming it's the worse-case-scenario), and modify the path for `PageNotFound` like following:

```
<Route path="/" component= {require('./components/app')} >
  <IndexRoute  component={ require('./components/homePage')} />
  <Route path="/about" component={require('./components/aboutPage')} />
  <Redirect from="/azaza" to="/about"/>
  <Route path="/*" component={PageNotFound} />
</Route>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Sorry. Have you ever tryed this solution before? Also routes doesn't work without Link in header elements. Seems new router version doesn't stable yet.